# Проверка заполнения поля формы

Tags: javascript, jquery, форма, скрипт, submit

Есть поле (одно из нескольких в форме, но речь именно об этом поле):

```
<textarea class="form-message" name="user_message" id="" cols="60" rows="10" placeholder="Your message"></textarea>
```

Кнопка:

```
<button class="form-btn" type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary" disabled>Send</button>
```

Обращение к файлу скрипта внизу перед footer:

```
<script src="js/trap.js"></script>
```

Содержимое файла скрипта:

```
function checkParams() {

    var trap = $('#trap').val();

    if(trap.length == 0) {
        $('#submit').removeAttr('disabled');
    } else {
        $('#submit').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
}
```

Чего пытаюсь добиться:
- если поле пустое, то кнопка активна
- если в поле есть символы, то кнопка НЕактивна

Что получилось:
- изначально, когда поле пустое, кнопка неактивна
- после ввода символов кнопка неактивна
- после удаления введенных символов кнопка становится активной (а надо чтобы была активной уже после загрузки страницы и вырубалась если вводятся символы)

Что нужно докрутить?

P.S. Прошу не обращать внимание на то что взят JQuiery и можно делать без него, взял что есть, докрутил как мог, остался один шаг...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оно?

```js
function checkParams() {
  var textarea = $('#textarea').val();
  if (textarea.length != 0) {
    $("#submit").prop('disabled', true);
  } else {
    $("#submit").prop('disabled', false);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea class="form-message" name="user_message" id="textarea" cols="60" rows="10" onkeyup='checkParams()' placeholder="Your message"></textarea>
<button class="form-btn" type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>
```

Comment: Спасибище! Оно!